# Can not open output file

Tags: c++

So I am a very very new to programming. like, solving for problems and while and things like that. I was using include  for working with files.

```
ifstream f("psp.in");
ofstream g("psp.out);
```

I have worked like that before and I didn't have any problems, but for some reasons, now, everytime I try to open the psp.out file, it doesn't do anything.
I ussually write the information in the .in file which I create and then the program solves the problem and I open the .out file to see the answer. But now I don't know why it is not opening.

Comment: Close all applications and try again - if failing, reboot.

Comment: It's still not working

Comment: Write the simplest program you can to write the file (`g << "hello";`) and try it. If it writes nothing, test the stream (`if(!g.good()) cout << "not good" << endl;`) and tell us the result.

Comment: Does your program have permission to create and write files in the directory of your executable?

Comment: Why do you say that the file is not opening? Is it because it doesn't have the contents you expect it to? Is it because it's not being created on disk (and it didn't exist before you ran your program)? You need to provide more detail...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what problem exactly are you having. You are alsoo required to share the code to help us help you better.

There's other ways you could do this.
First, if you are trying algorithmic questions of competitive type, you can use input redirection.

In windows openn command prompt `"your_program < psp.in > psp.out"`. This way you won't be needing to use file handling at all. You could also

Or you could simply use the functions fread and fwrite which works for both linux and windows.

> FILE *f = fopen("psp.in",O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
>   fread(&buffer,size_of_data_type_to_be_read,no_of_such_data_items_to_be_read,fd);

Similarly you can use fwrite to write to a file.

Comment: Even assuming that `fwrite` is an acceptable substitute for everything that can be done with an `ofstream`, how can you be sure that `fwrite` would work at all? It might be a problem with the file system, or the code that calls the write operations.